# Write two single line functions to encode and decode base64

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

Write two functions of one line each that can encode and decode base64.

- Use any language you want, but if the language can naturally be converted to a single line (e.g. javascript) then any block of code separated by an end-of-line character is counted as a line.
- The functions must be self-contained. They cannot reference outside variables or imported libraries, with the exception of a single input argument.
- Expanding on the previous point, you cannot define constants or variables for use inside the function. For instance, if your function references `alphabet` as the collection of base64 symbols, replace every instance of `alphabet` with a literal of the same value.
- The functions must be one line each, not counting the function definition itself. For example, in languages like Visual Basic, functions are a minimum of three lines due to the beginning and end lines being a required part of the function definition. This is acceptable as long as the code that does the base64 conversion is only one line.
- Do not use built in functions such as javascript's `atob` or `btoa`.

Here's my functions written in python. I can't find a way to make these smaller.

```
def tobase64(m):
    return ''.join(['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'[int(z[::-1].zfill(6)[::-1],2)] for z in [''.join([bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(8)for x in m])[y:y+6] for y in range(0,len(m)*8,6)]])+''.join(['=' for x in range(-len(m)%3)])
```

and the decoder

```
def fromb64(m):
    return ''.join([chr(int(w,2)) for w in [(''.join([''.join([bin('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'.index(x))[2:].zfill(6) for x in m if x in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'])[y:y+8] for y in range(0,len(''.join([bin('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'.index(x))[2:].zfill(6) for x in m if x in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'])),8)])+'a')[:-(len(m)-len(m.replace('=','')))*2-1][z:z+8] for z in range(0,len(''.join([bin('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'.index(x))[2:].zfill(6) for x in m if x in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'])),8)] if len(w) == 8])
```

Comment: JavaScript, for one, has built-in functions that do exactly that, `atob` and `btoa`. You may want to disallow builtin functions that do this task.

Comment: @NinjaBearMonkey Edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: Also, which [base64 variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)?

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 437 characters

As a first improvement to your Python solution, you can cut down on the references to the long string of characters 'abc...ABC...0123456789+/':

```
def fromb64(m):
    return (lambda A:''.join([chr(int(w,2)) for w in [(''.join([''.join([bin(A.index(x))[2:].zfill(6) for x in m if x in A])[y:y+8] for y in range(0,len(''.join([bin(A.index(x))[2:].zfill(6) for x in m if x in A])),8)])+'a')[:-(len(m)-len(m.replace('=','')))*2-1][z:z+8] for z in range(0,len(''.join([bin(A.index(x))[2:].zfill(6) for x in m if x in A])),8)] if len(w)==8]))('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/')
```

This is just (lambda A: {{what you did, but with that string replaced by A}})(that string).

Comment: Very clever! I didn't think to use lambda functions.